# cmake echoes an empty CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR

Tags: cmake, clion

I am using cmake with Clion which has version:

```
>     /snap/clion/189/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --version
```

> ```
> cmake version 3.22.3
>
> CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
> ```

When configuring my cmake project with this version I get following error:

```
CMake Error at test/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_program):
  Could not find TEST_WITH_DATA using the following names:


 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Line 6:

```
find_program(TEST_WITH_DATA REQUIRED "test_with_data.sh" PATHS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

I really cannot see what the problem is here?

with cmake version 3.16.3 it does work!

Comment: How about this: `find_program(TEST_WITH_DATA "test_with_data.sh" REQUIRED PATHS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")`?

Comment: unfortunately no. Wondering if this is related to the cmake version itself or the cmake bundled version that gets shipped with the Clion software

Comment: You see, `REQUIRED` was introduced in 3.18 so whatever works for you in 3.16.3 might be because of something else in your project file(s)

Comment: That line should find what you search for as long as `test_with_data.sh` exists in `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"`

Comment: it does indeed. Otherwise, the 3.16.3 would not compile. Regarding REQUIRED then yes it does not work on either versions.